# valid file path

Tags: c#, path, filepath

Is this file path valid?:

> 'C:sample.txt'

(this string is input from a user)

It is confusing since there's no error returned. I've used Directory.Exists(path.DirectoryName).
But I cannot find the file created in C:.

Answer (score 4):

it is created in your current directory

```
        string filepath = "c:sample.txt";

        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath);
        sw.WriteLine("hello");
        sw.Close();

        string s = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `C:sample.txt` is a valid file path, and refers to whatever the process current directory for drive `C:` is (since no specific directory is provided in the path).

Comment: The OS has a "current directory" for each process and for each drive letter. So when you use `C:sample.txt`, Windows uses the current directory for drive C: for your process. What that current directory is depends on how your process was started and what it has already done previously.

Answer (score 1):

It indeed is a corret path, Windows doesnt bother with a \.

Also try and use File.Exists().

Answer (score 0):

path must be as follows,

```
       string filePath=args[0]
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

It must be changed to

```
C:\sample.txt
```